# How can I paint a rectangle around a window without overriding the title bar in win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to draw a rectangle around my window but I don't want to override the title bar.
what I wrote so far in the window callback function is:

```
    case WM_NCPAINT:
    {
        HDC hdc;
        RECT rect;
        HPEN pen;

        hdc=GetDCEx(hWnd,(HRGN)wParam,DCX_WINDOW|DCX_CACHE|DCX_INTERSECTRGN|DCX_LOCKWINDOWUPDATE);
        GetWindowRect(hWnd,&rect);
        pen=CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 10, RGB(255, 0, 0));//red pen 10 pixels in size
        SelectObject(hdc,pen);
        Rectangle(hdc,0,0,(rect.right-rect.left),(rect.bottom-rect.top));
        DeleteObject(pen);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd,hdc);
    }
    break;
```

However, this draws over the window title bar with white brush.

How can I make it not to paint over the title bar? I'm loosing the title bar text and the menu...

I have tried using HOLLOW_BRUSH before creating the pen as follows:

```
        HBRUSH b=CreateSolidBrush(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
        SelectObject(hdc,b);
```

But that only caused the title bar to not be drawn at all (being black).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By handling the `WM_NCPAINT` message, you are telling the window manager that you are taking responsibility for painting the entire non-client area, and so the window manager will not draw any of it for you.

If you want the original title bar to be drawn then you need to call `DefWindowProc()` first, then do your own drawing "on top" of what it draws.

You may also need to use [`ExcludeClipRect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162702(v=vs.85).aspx) to prevent the client area from being drawn over if you wish to draw the entire non-client area at once with a single rectangle.